# Permutation of coordinates -- looking for a notational advice

Tags: permutations, notation

I am looking for notational advice.

I have a set of $n$ points in which the value of some coordinate $z$ remains constant and the values of all other coordinates permute. Thus, for any  $n$  there are $(n-1)!$ points like this. Example with $n=3$:

$$p_1=(x,y,z), $$
$$p_2=(y,x,z) .$$

How would one concisely write down the set of all coordinates like this in a general form?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

The set of all $(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n-1)},x_n)$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation of the set $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$?

Comment: Thank you! It will do. I guess it should be something similar if my fixed coordinate is in the `middle'.

Comment: @Oleh: I guess if $i$ is the coordinate you want to be fixed you could talk about the set of all $(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})$ as $\sigma$ ranges over permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that fix $i$.

Comment: @MikeF I am sorry, I did not get it. What does `$\sigma$ ranges over' mean? I am sorry if the question is silly.

Comment: For example, "the set of all $2n+1$ as $n$ ranges over the positive integers" means the same thing as $\{2n+1: \text{$n$ is a positive integer} \}$.